# How can I capture all groups and replace them with the reformatted version of the group?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

**TEXT IN:**

```
some "single , quote" , text ""{one,2two space,three-dash,four}"" "{some,text}"  ""{alpha,bravo space - dash,charlie}"" some text
```

**TEXT OUT:**

```
some "single , quote" , text ""{one","2two space","three-dash","four}"" "{some,text}"  ""{alpha","bravo space - dash","charlie}"" some text
```

*I have a javascript solution below that works, but i'm wondering if there is a better solution?*

```
const str = "some \"single , quote\" , text \"\"\{one,2two space,three-dash,four\}\"\" \"\{some,text\}\"  \"\"\{alpha,bravo space - dash,charlie\}\"\" some text"
let res = str;
const matches = res.match(/""{([^"])*}""/g);
matches?.forEach( match => {
   res = res.replace(match, match.replace(/,/g,'","'));
});
console.log(str); // TEXT IN
console.log(res); // TEXT OUT
```

Comment: Helpful hint: If your string contains double quotes, use single quotes around it so you don't need to escape the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a function as the replacement argument to the `replace()` method, so you don't need the loop.

Also, your regexp can be simplified. You don't need the capture group, just put the `*` quantifier after `[^"]`

```js
const str = 'some, text ""{one,2two space,three-dash,four}"" some, text ""{alpha,bravo space - dash,charlie}"" some text';

res = str.replace(/""{[^"]*}""/g, match => match.replace(/,/g, '","'))
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This solution is great!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression to match commas that are to be replaced with (the three-character string) `'","'`.

```
/(?<=""{[^{}\n]*),(?=[^{}\n]*}"")/
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/Or9rtF/2/)

This is possible because Javascript supports *variable-length* lookbehinds.

For the string

```
some, text ""{one,2two space,three-dash,four}"" some, text ""{alpha,bravo space - dash,charlie}"" some text';
```

the matching and replacements results in the string

```
some, text ""{one","2two space","three-dash","four}"" some, text ""{alpha","bravo space - dash","charlie}"" some text';
```

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=        : begin a positive lookbehind
  ""{       : match '""{'
  [^{}\n]*  : match 0+ chars other than those shown in the char class
)           : end positive lookbehind
,           : match ','
(?=         : begin positive lookahead
  [^{}\n]*  : match 0+ chars other than those shown in the char class
  }""       : match '}""'
)           : end positive lookahead
```

Comment: Nice, appreciate the detailed explanation!